# Hide Dispform content from users

Tags: dispform

I am new to Sharepoint, i need to hide from users the content from a url like this:
https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/mywebsite/Lists/mylist/DispForm.aspx?ID=123.

How can it be done? some say that only a redirect can be aplyed, how can i apply a simple javascript redirect into this url?

Thank´s in advance

Comment: Do you know if you are using a modern UI or a classic UI?

Comment: a modern, we have the last version of sharepoint on the cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to hide contents of the form is to customize the form with Power App. [Read more about it here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form).

- Open an existing list item.
- Click ... > Customize with power Apps:

[image]

- Then you can hide/show any fields based on a condition of your choice. For example, you can check if the user has enough permissions to view the content.
- Save and publish the form.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Denis i will try the solution

Comment: This will maintain the form public (the expected behaviour) ? and only hide the itens sent from the form (the expected behaviour) ?

Comment: Yes, the form won't have any changes permission-wise. If your list was public, it will remain so. Hiding and showing of the form contents will happen based on the logic you define in the Power App form.

Comment: work as expected, thank you Denis